# Where can I find this piece in LDD V4.3.11?

Tags: piece-information, ldd

I am building a mech in LDD V4.3.11 and I need this piece for the head sculpt of the mech. I can't find it anywhere in the toolbox, with and without using the search box above. Where can I find this piece (Part No. 14704)?

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14704#T=C

Comment: Strange, I have a slightly older version of LDD, version 4.3.10, brick Version 2248.1
The element is present both in standard and extended mode there.

Comment: That is very strange. Thanks to @MichaelVerschaeve's answer, I found it only in Extended mode, and not Standard Mode. I think Lego made this part a legacy part for some bizarre reason.

Comment: There's no reason for this part being considered a legacy part. From bricklink you can check in which sets it was present and sort by year released, still plenty of 2018 sets having it... One reason I can think of for moving it to extended mode is the difficulty one might experience in LDD when modelling connections with it...

Comment: Maybe. But the part works relatively well in Extended mode of LDD, so I fail to see why Lego just wouldn't put this in Standard mode for mech makers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried in version 4.3.10. The element is present both in standard and extended mode.
I updated to version 4.3.11, had to update anyway as 4.3.10 apparently wasn't supported anymore and only worked offline.
In the standard mode, I can confirm element 14704 is not present.
However, if you switch to extended mode (Main menu -> View -> New themes -> extended), it's present.
Unfortunately the extended mode let's you build in colors that might not exist...
I hope this gets addressed in a next update as to me this seems a standard element.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I had to abandon my mech build after so long because of one stupid but essential part. I can confirm that the part is there in the extended version of LDD V4.3.11